# MySQL (customers to orders)

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with php, mysql and I want to do exactly what
[this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) link says.

In the w3schools example it prints:

```
   NAME                  ORDER NO. 
Ola Hansen                22245 
Ola Hansen                47475
Ola Hansen                45854
```

But I need:

```
   NAME                  ORDER NO.
Ola Hansen          22245, 47475, 45854
```

It has to do with data manipulation on PHP or do I need to change something on the query....?

Thanks in advance,

Niki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways are possible.

You can use group_concat() in mysql (along with GROUP BY of course). But keep in mind that default size of the data returned by this function is just 1024 bytes.

Or you can do it with data manipulation in PHP - sometimes it's going to be more flexible

Comment: You can increase the size of the `group_concat` by using `group_concat_max_len` but that involves a config change

Comment: You can juset set it at runtime I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT
    `NAME`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`ORDER NO.` AS CHAR) SEPARATOR ', ') AS `ORDER NO.`
FROM
(
    -- your query
) AS T1
GROUP BY `NAME`
```

Answer (score 0):

> It has to do with data manipulation on PHP

Yes, it is the best way.

Comment: yes.. and that's my problem. how can i say in PHP {if the customers name is the SAME with the previous then print ONLY the order no. ELSE print the next customers name}

Comment: Users shoulbe in table 'users' with structure 'id', 'name', 'etc'

Comment: Users should be in table 'users' with structure 'id', 'name', 'etc', orders with structure 'user_id', 'order_no'. With user_id you can do everything, for example, you can collect data to array and work with it